# Vmware Player is not seeing the operating system when setting up the virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player, setup

I am using windows 7 host and installed a new player the other day. I tried to use puppy as an osi and the player wont see it...

I then tried another osi and it would not recognize that one in the setup process either.

Any Ideas why this would be happening - i am leaning towards windows 7 because it ran perfect on the laptop with xp